# how to use layout templat in asp.net wizard control?

Tags: asp.net, wizard

i have read somewhere about using layout template in asp.net wizard control but when iam using the same in my code a parser error is generated

'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard' does not have a public property named 'LayoutTemplate'.

is there any way to solve this or is it true that it is not possible to use layout template in wizard control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i founded one answer that this (LayoutTemplate) is supported in dot net framework 4 and mine is 3.5 may be because of this.